# Is there any extension in vs code about how to know all files who imported the current file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

exported default class ButtonNoclickTag {...}

I would know what files imported this ButtonNoClickTag component using vscode

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour, visit the help center, and read up on asking good questions. After doing some research and searching for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Vs Code can do that without any extensions:
right-click onto the name (in your case `ButtonNoclickTag`) and select `Find All References`.